# AngularJS : Is this the correct way to chain promises?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, chaining, angular-promise

I have a function *foo* that calls another function *moreFoo* and I want to wrap the function calls in promises so that the promise returned by *foo* returns after *moreFoo* has resolved. Here is my solution:

```
function foo() {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  console.log('doing foo');
  moreFoo().then(defer.resolve);
  return defer.promise;
}

function moreFoo() {
  var defer = $q.defer();
  setTimeout(function() {
    console.log('doing more foo');
    defer.resolve();
  }, 2000);
  return defer.promise;
}

foo().then(function() {
  console.log('finished with all foos');
});
```

This then outputs:

> ```
> doing foo
> doing more foo
> finished with all foos
> ```

It appears to be working as intended. Is this the correct/best way to chain these promises?

Comment: What is your criteria for "correct/best?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about "best", but this can be simplified a lot by leveraging `$timeout` the promise it returns...

```
function foo() {
  console.log('doing foo');
  return moreFoo();
}

function moreFoo() {
  return $timeout(function() {
    console.log('doing more foo');
  }, 2000);
}

foo().then(function() {
  console.log('finished with all foos');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this way ( $timeout returns promise):

```
 function foo() {
      return $timeout(function(){
           console.log('doing foo');
       },2000);
 }

 function moreFoo() {
      return $timeout(function(){
           console.log('doing more foo');
       },2000);
 }        

 foo()
     .then(moreFoo)
     .then(function(){ 
          console.log('all foos done');
      }, function() {
         console.log('something went wrong');
      });
```

This example shows two promises chained together. The second executes only after the first one succeeds. If either fails, the last error handler is called.

Answer (score 0):

Can run both simultaneously and not even need to chain them by using `$q.all()`

```
$q.all([ foo(), moreFoo()]).then(function(data){
    console.log(data) /* array of responses from all resolved promises */
});
```

Good reference: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-q-all